# Is it possible to make a Wikipedia search gadget in HTML?

Tags: html, search, wikipedia

I was wondering how to make a Wikipedia search gadget in HTML code. This gadget is for a personal blog that I am working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a form redirecting on submit or load the target page via ajax etc.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial%3ASuche&search=%s

Where `%s` is your search query. Like:
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial%3ASuche&search=test

```
<form method="GET" action="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="Spezial%3ASuche" />    
    <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/CkK3j/

Comment: see also http://www.askdavetaylor.com/add_wikipedia_search_box_to_my_web_site_or_blog.html

Comment: I dont really know what you mean. Can you put in the code for it

Comment: @EandCProducts see the link in my above comment